# Format all files with a specific file extension with Prettier

Tags: formatting, format, prettier

Is it possible to format exclusively all files with a specific file extension with Prettier?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to have prettier installed

```
npm install --global prettier
```

Say, you only want to target files with the `js` extension: from the directory you want to format, run:

```
prettier --write "**/*.js"
```